# How can I get the value of a class attribute of a list into a new list?

Tags: python, list

I have a list called "citizens". This list has a class Citizen attached to it which is populated as shown below (where Citizen is a class with a few attributes:

```
citizens=[]

for i  in range(N):
        citizens.append(Citizen(is_infected,
                                l1,
                                l2,
                                c,
                                i))
```

I'd like to extract a list of the attribute is_infected such that the list is a boolean (in this case) and of length N.

Thanks!

Comment: So what instance attribute does the first argument set? Do you want `[c.is_infected for c in citizens]`?

Comment: Kind of. But the issue is that if I am trying to refer to that attribute, I have to refer to it as citizens[0].is_infected. I basically want to pull out the "is_infected" attribute for all citizens into a list. And when I use [c.is_infected for c in citizens], the error says: " 'Citizen' object has no attribute 'is_infected'"

Comment: I'm not sure what the difference between `c.is_infected` (when `c` is the first element of the list) and `citizens[0].is_infected` could be. Are you sure `Citizen.__init__` always sets the `is_infected` attribute?

Comment: Posted a (minimal) definition of the class that reproduces the error.